# Php Dropdown menu - Connect to another DB and show them

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

i work with vuejs3 and laravel 9 on one project.
i have two DB_table. Employee and company.
Company has only id and company name.
Employee contains: id, first name, last name, email, and company_id as forign key, which was joined to id in company_table.

If you want to create a new employee, you have to enter above mentioned infos and select a company name from selectbox (which is shown in previously entered companies) and save it in the table. How can I do then?

[image]

```
@extends('mitarbeiter.layout')
@section('content')
 
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">Mitarbeiter Page</div>
  <div class="card-body">
      
      <form action="{{ url('mitarbeiter') }}" method="post">
        {!! csrf_field() !!}

        <label>Vorname</label></br>
        <input type="text" name="vorname" id="vorname" class="form-control"></br>

        <label>Nachname</label></br>
        <input type="text" name="nachname" id="nachname" v-model="mitarbeiter.nachname" class="form-control"></br>

        <label>Email</label></br>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control"></br>



        <label>Company</label></br>
        <select>
          <option value="">------Select Company-------</option>
          <option name="companyname">
              {{option.companyname}}
          </option>
        </select></br>

        </br>



        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success"></br>
    </form>
   
  </div>
</div>
 
@stop
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreach like this :

```
 <select name="company" class="form-control">
           @foreach ($companies as $company)
            <option value="{{ $company->id }}">{{$company->name}}</option>
          @endforeach
          </select>
```

and in the controller :

```
    $company = Companies::find($id);
    $employee = new Employee();
    $employee->user_id = $request->company; //name of select
    $employee->company_id = $id;
    $employee->save();
```

hope this would help

Comment: i have two controllers (company and Employee) and they have index,create,store, show, edit and update function. where should i write it for controllers?

Comment: It won't matter because you called both tables, create a function in either controller that adds user to company and use both models in that controller.
you may also add it in store function if you like.